# Exception when creating a role on Ceph Object Gateway using Java AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-iam, ceph, aws-sts, radosgw

I am trying to follow the Ceph documentation's [examples](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/STS/#examples) to test its STS functionality using the Java AWS SDK (v 2.5.16). It is failing rather early on in the process when calling the IamClient's createRole method. The exception thrown is:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.model.IamException: null (Service: Iam, Status Code: 403, Request ID: tx0000000000000000000f4-005f689d69-396f9b-default)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleErrorResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:115)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:73)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:58)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:41)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:64)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:77)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:39)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.doExecute(RetryableStage.java:113)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.execute(RetryableStage.java:86)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:62)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:57)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:240)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:96)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:120)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:73)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:44)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.iam.DefaultIamClient.createRole(DefaultIamClient.java:1406)
```

so there is not much to go on.

The user whose credentials are being used in calling the API has the following settings
(obtained by running`radosgw-admin user info --uid admin-api-user` on the command line)

```
{
    "user_id": "admin-api-user",
    "display_name": "Admin API User",
    "email": "",
    "suspended": 0,
    "max_buckets": 1000,
    "subusers": [],
    "keys": [
        {
            "user": "admin-api-user",
            "access_key": "abc",
            "secret_key": "xyz"
        }
    ],
    "swift_keys": [],
    "caps": [
        {
            "type": "buckets",
            "perm": "*"
        },
        {
            "type": "metadata",
            "perm": "*"
        },
        {
            "type": "usage",
            "perm": "*"
        },
        {
            "type": "users",
            "perm": "*"
        },
        {
            "type": "zone",
            "perm": "*"
        }
    ],
    "op_mask": "read, write, delete",
    "default_placement": "",
    "default_storage_class": "",
    "placement_tags": [],
    "bucket_quota": {
        "enabled": false,
        "check_on_raw": false,
        "max_size": -1,
        "max_size_kb": 0,
        "max_objects": -1
    },
    "user_quota": {
        "enabled": false,
        "check_on_raw": false,
        "max_size": -1,
        "max_size_kb": 0,
        "max_objects": -1
    },
    "temp_url_keys": [],
    "type": "rgw",
    "mfa_ids": []
}
```

When instead of trying to create the role using the Java SDK, I create it from the command line by running

```
radosgw-admin role create --role-name=test --assume-role-policy-doc=\{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":\[\{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\{\"AWS\":\[\"arn:aws:iam:::user/TESTER\"\]\},\"Action\":\[\"sts:AssumeRole\"\]\}\]\}
```

it works fine. Any hints at what might be causing the problem would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I just figured out that the [documentation](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/admin/#add-remove-admin-capabilities) does not list all the available admin capabilities that one can assign to a user. So apart from those in the user info listing above, there are two more which can be added, namely "roles" and "user-policy". I stumbled across those in a user info sample on [this](http://lists.ceph.com/pipermail/ceph-users-ceph.com/2019-March/033687.html) mailing list entry.
Once I added the "roles" capability, the createRole call succeeds.